# Replacing Esri branding with custom graphic in web app

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-web-appbuilder

Although there appears to be an easy way to remove the "Powered by ESRI" graphic in JSON I would like, rather than removing it, to substitute it with a custom PNG.

When I set `"Logo": false,` in "mapOptions" the Esri logo turns off but if I set the logo to an existing valid PNG, rather than displaying it, the custom graphic is somehow over-ridden and the "Powered by ESRI" graphic is displayed.

How do I replace the default with a custom graphic?

Default graphic:

[image]

Setting the logo to a valid PNG has no effect:

[image]

Setting the logo to false works!

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Is this allowed in their ToS?

Comment: Have you tried a full path to the image? `http://www.domain.com/path/to/png.png`? Just a thought.

Comment: I would hope its allowed. After spending huge money on the tech I don't want the vendor logo plastered all over our maps that will only contain 100% of our own content.

Comment: @ChadCooper - good suggestion! I put the fully qualified hyperlink (texted in browser so I am certain it's correct) to the image in the code and again the esri logo is displayed instead.

Comment: Wait, so you put the full URL to _your_ image and it displayed the esri logo instead?

Comment: This could probably be achieved with a `<div>` and some CSS styling.

Comment: @ChadCooper - yes.  i can turn it off but if i attempt to stick in any other graphic it's overridden by the default esri logo.  this includes a valid fully qualified path to my image.

Comment: @Mintx - i don't seem to be able to find any style sheets that would contain a reference to this image in the web app directory.

Comment: @Jakub Sorry, I meant hiding the ESRI logo and using a div to overlay your own image on the web page in a fixed position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "logo" option is documented as being a Boolean value that defaults to true. So if you put false, it won't show it; if you enter any value (or leave it off so it defaults to true), it will show their logo. (This is because JavaScript interprets any non-null value as true.) So you're left with the option to set it to false, and float your own logo over the map.

Answer (score 2):

As [@BillB says](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/197976/115) this is the solution. To add your own logo in Javascript I found the following works.

In the index.html file:
Add a css style:

```
    #logo{ 
        position: absolute; 
        z-index: 100000; 
        bottom: 5%; 
        right: 1%;}
```

Add a div:

```
<div id="logo"> <img src="linktoimage source" width="200" > </div>
```

This puts my logo in the bottom right hand corner.